# Responsive not working after converting html theme to drupal theme

Tags: html, css, drupal

While trying to convert a HTML responsive theme to Drupal 7 theme, it's responsive is not working!!!

Can anyone help me with this to sort the issue? We have copied Bartik theme and removed the CSS and pasted the HTML5 theme CSS and js that we created...changed the `index.tpl` into page -- `front.tpl.php` and copied it into the template folder.....in the page -- `front.tpl.php` we give all the path for CSS and js as:

```
<?php $path="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>
<link rel="icon" href="$path.">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path.base_path().path_to_theme()?>/css/style.css">. As specified we gave path for all css and js files,but don;t know where we went wrong!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Might it be because you dont have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

in your head?

Comment: we added the above stated code then also its not working!!!The page still remains unresponsive.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website?

Comment: we are still developing a single page website,as we are beginners to drupal 7,while testing the content we came to know that single page is not responsive.we need to know the how to delete or remove the css file permenanently from a theme and add our created css into the theme and where to add this code i.e in which file?as stated below we used hook_css_alter to unset that css ,but its not working...function will_css_alter(&$css) { if () { //Unset CSS file if the current page is your custom page $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'will'); unset($css[$path . '/css/main.css']); } } "